# Proper way to implement a whitelist

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda and have a question how to properly implement a whitelist in Corda.

Let's assume a fungible security token is issued on Corda that has to meet a certain kind of regulation (e.g., the investor is not allowed to be from a certain country). Therefore a whitelist would be required to make sure that all regulation requirements are met.

In a private network I assume that there is no need for an actual whitelist, as the issuer who runs the node can control who is allowed to join the network and who isn't. 
But on the public Corda network there are potentially many identities who are not allowed to hold a certain type of token and a whitelist would be required.

What would be the proper design choice for this kind of problem?
I thought about having a `WhitelistState` which holds a set of all whitelisted investors. But if I understood correctly, each participant of the state (in this case the issuer and the investors) would have to sign a transaction if a new investor was added or removed from the whitelist, which is not a suitable solution.

I would appreciate any helpful advice on how to solve such an issue!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `blacklist` project in the samples repo:
https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/blacklist

Essentially what they do:
1. Inside `ReachAgreementFlow` they add an attachment to the transaction, that attachment is a jar file that contains `blacklist.txt` file.
2. Inside the state contract `AgreementContract` (which validates the transaction) they extract the jar and read its contents and make sure that the company listed in the agreement is not part of the blacklist.

Comment: On a side note, I recommend that you get the entire samples repo; there are many good things you can learn from exploring it. Spend some time to at least read the **README** file of each project.